# Cannot access sObjectType 'OrgWideEmailAddress'

Tags: permissions, profile, apex-email-service, sobjecttype

I am encountering an exceptionally unusual issue.

I have a **User A** (running under **Profile A**). This profile has minimal permissions. It has only **Permission Set A**

**Permission Set A** gives "View Setup and Configuration" so that users with that permission can query for Organization-Wide Email Addresses.

I have a **User B** (running under **Profile B**). This profile has minimal permissions. It has only **Permission Set A**

**User A** cannot query for the Organization-Wide Email Address and gets "sObjectType for 'orgwideemailaddress' not supported.

**User B** can query for the Organization-Wide Email Address.

They are both calling the same APEX class which they both have permission to. This class uses **with sharing** and the lookup for the Organization-Wide Email Address has **WITH SECURITY ENFORCED**.

The profiles are in 3 of our environments **INT**, **STG**, and **PROD**.

In INT and STG both the users can access the Org Wide Email Address. In **PROD** only **User B** can.

The setup is pretty much exactly the same between the environments.

What am I missing here that could be causing this issue with **User A**? Is there something that could restrict access to that object? They do have "**View Setup and Configuration**" and as far as I know this should be all that's required to lookup that field.

And just to be clear I have confirmed both **Profile A** and **Profile B** are Allowed profiles in the Organization-Wide Email Address.

Comment: try https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/ in PROD to compare the two users A and B; perhaps some insight will be obtained

Comment: I sadly cannot use a tool like that - our environments are super locked down.

Comment: muting permission sets?